# Two columns height equal using css

Tags: html, css, less

Inside container div i have two columns. Column 1 height is dynamic, I want column 2 height to match according with column 1. I tried using `display: table` property but it's not working. How can i achieve it using css? I get this problem when column 1 displays errors and it's height increases. How do i set both column same height using css?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">    
                <div class="row">  
                    <div class="col-md-7 pr-0">
                        <section class="tile new-su-tile1">
                            <!-- tile body -->
                            <div class="tile-body p-40">
                                <form name="signupForm" role="form" ng-submit="userSignupMethod(signupForm)" novalidate>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-model="userSignup.firstname"
                                                       ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your Name" id="firstname" >
                                                <span ng-messages="((signupForm.firstname.$touched && signupForm.firstname.$error) || (signupForm.$submitted && signupForm.firstname.$error))"
                                                      role="alert">
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="required">Please complete this mandatory field.</span>
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="pattern">Please enter valid name.</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" ng-model="userSignup.lastname"
                                                       ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/"
                                                       required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your Last Name" id="lastname" >
                                                <span ng-messages="((signupForm.lastname.$touched && signupForm.lastname.$error) || (signupForm.$submitted && signupForm.lastname.$error))"
                                                      role="alert">
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="required">Please complete this mandatory field.</span>
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="pattern">Please enter valid name.</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="userSignup.email"
                                                       ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-z-A-Z.]{2,50}$/" required autocomplete="off" id="email" placeholder="Your Email ID">
                                                <span ng-messages="((signupForm.email.$touched && signupForm.email.$error) || (signupForm.$submitted && signupForm.email.$error))"
                                                      role="alert">
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="required">Please complete this mandatory field.</span>
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="pattern">Please enter valid email.</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactnumber" ng-model="userSignup.contactnumber"
                                                       ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,15}$/" autocomplete="off" id="contactnumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" minlength="10" maxlength="15">
                                                <span ng-messages="((signupForm.contactnumber.$touched && signupForm.contactnumber.$error) || (signupForm.$submitted && signupForm.contactnumber.$error))"
                                                      role="alert">
                                                    <span class="error_msg" ng-message="pattern">Please enter valid contact number.</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
                                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-login b-0 br-2 mr-5" analytics-event="click" analytics-category="sign up">Sign Up</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                    

                                    <!-- Modal HTML ng-disabled="enquiryForm.$invalid "-->
                                    <div id="successSignUp" class="modal fade modal-md thank-you">
                                        <div id="loadingImag" ng-if="loadingImag" class="content-center">
                                            <a href="" class="myIcon icon-info icon-ef-6 icon-color">
                                                <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="messageBox" ng-if="messageBox" class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                                            <div class="modal-content content-center modal-md ">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                            aria-hidden="true">x
                                                    </button>
                                                    <h2 class="modal-title">Thank You</h2>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <div class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="messageColor ? 'text-success' : 'text-lightred'" data-ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
                                                        {{alert.message}} <br>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-ef btn-ef-3"
                                                            ng-click="redirecttoSinup()">OK
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /tile body -->
                            <!-- tile footer -->
                            <div class="tile-footer new-tile-footer text-center ">
                                <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
                                <p class="pt-5">Already a user?
                                <a ui-sref="login" class="login-link">Log in to your account</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /tile footer -->
                        </section>
                        <!-- /tile -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 pl-0">
                        <section class="tile new-su-tile2">
                            <div class="ysu-heading pt-36">Why Sign Up?</div>
                            <ul class="pl-0">
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>Apply & Manage your Visa Applications with Ease</li>
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>Store all Visa related documents in one secure vault for easy future reference </li>
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>Access your Visa related documents anytime, anywhere all ine one place</li>
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>All your data is stored making re-applying easier and faster</li>
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>Automatically fills in your Visa form next time you need to travel</li>
                                <li class="ysu-subheading"><i class="fa fa-check pr-8 pt-2 ysu-icon"></i>Tag your family as applicants</li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>    
        </div>  
        <div ng-include="'components/navbar/quick-links.html'"></div>  
    </div>
```

**CSS (less format)**

```
.new-su-tile1 {
    & .form-control {
        height: 38px;
        border: 1px solid #acacac;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    & .error_msg {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    & .btn-login {
        background: #32a9de;
    }
}

.new-su-main-tile2 {
    margin-left: -1px;
    & .new-su-tile2 {
        min-height: 308px;
        @media ( max-width:@screen-xs-max) { 
            border-left: 1px solid #acacac;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: -15px;
         }
         @media ( max-width:@screen-sm-max) {
            border-left: 1px solid #acacac;
            margin-left: 15px;
            margin-right: -15px;
         }
        & .ysu-heading {
        color: #86c049; 
        text-align: center;
        }
        & .ysu-subheading {
            list-style: none;
            color: #333333;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline-flex;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left !important;
            padding: 8px 0;
            &:first-child {
                padding-top: 25px;
            }
            /*&:last-child {
                padding-bottom: 29px;
            }*/
            & .ysu-icon {
                font-size: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}   

.new-tile-footer {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 12px;
    & .login-link {
        color: #32a9de !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+columns+equal+height

Comment: Update Sentences

Answer (score 0):

@user6371206 Please check following example. i hope you are expecting the same.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('features');
var elementHeights = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, (el) => {
  return el.clientHeight;
});

var maxHeight = Math.max(...elementHeights)

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, (el) => el.style.height = `${maxHeight}px`);
```

```css
.a { height: 30px; background-color: red; }
.b { height: 220px; background-color: aqua; }
.c { height: 50px; background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="features a"></div>
<div class="features b"></div>
<div class="features c"></div>
```